# Why am I returning duplicates in a 2D List during a level order tree traversal?

Tags: java, data-structures

so this is leetcode question #102. The leetcode description of this question is: **Given a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).**

So given a tree like

```
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7
```

should return

```
[
  [3],
  [9,20],
  [15,7]
]
```

My code is below

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        Queue<TreeNode> list = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        list.add(root);

        while(!list.isEmpty()){
            int size = list.size();
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while(size != 0){

                root = list.remove();

                if(root.left != null)  list.add(root.left);
                if(root.right != null) list.add(root.right);

                temp.add(root.val);

                size--;
                res.add(temp);
            }
        }
        return res;   
    }
}
```

How come when I leave `res.add(temp)` inside the second while loop, it returns the answer as: **[[3],[9,20],[9,20],[15,7],[15,7]]**

But when I put the `res.add(temp)` outside the second while loop, but inside the first, I get the correct answer. Also, sorry if this is formatted terribly or if I made this post a lot longer than I should have, still new to posting questions on stackoverflow. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first loop goes through the levels (the level is the current content of `list`):

```
    3            one list for level 0: [3]
   / \           
  9  20          one list for level 1: [9, 20]
    /  \
   15   7        one list for level 2: [15, 7]
```

The second loop goes through the nodes on each level (`root` is a current node):

```
    3            one list for "3": [3]
   / \           
  9  20          one list for "9" [9, 20], the same list for "20": [9, 20]
    /  \
   15   7        one list for "15" [15, 7], the same list for "7" [15, 7]
```

You can output the current values of `list` and `root` to help you visualize the algorithm:

```
while(!list.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("First loop. Current level: "+list);
    int size = list.size();
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(size != 0) {
        root = list.remove();
        System.out.println("Second loop. Current node: "+root);

        if(root.left != null)  list.add(root.left);
        if(root.right != null) list.add(root.right);

        temp.add(root.val);
        size--;
        res.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I still dont see how it ends up as **  one list for "9" [9, 20], the same list for "20": [9, 20]** And what do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @CrisManrique I've updated my answer, see if this helps. In general, try to run this code step-by-step with a debugger.

Comment: Thank you! I found out why it was outputting like that. Thanks for your help